# Largest number of letters used in five-letter English words

Tags: wordle, word-game

What is the largest number of letters one can use in making five common five-letter words in the English language? The following list covers 23 letters:

TREND, SWAMP, BOUGH, FLICK, JAZZY

Is it possible to get to 24? What about 25?